# Using the JDBC Prepared Statement setNull() function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-sql

I have a Google Apps Script connecting to a Google Cloud SQL instance via JDBC. I am using prepared statements, and am running into trouble when trying to set a NULL value. To set any other kind of value, you just do:

```
 preparedStatement.setFloat(3, myFloatVar);
```

but I can't get setNull() to work. It is supposed to take a Java data type as an argument.
[Docs Link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc-prepared-statement#setNull%28Integer,Integer%29)

I've tried the following:

```
    preparedStatement.setNull(4,"java.sql.Types.DECIMAL");
    preparedStatement.setNull(4,java.sql.Types.DECIMAL);  <-- This is how you would do it in Java, I believe
    preparedStatement.setNull(4);
    preparedStatement.setNull(4,null);
    preparedStatement.setNull(4,"null");
```

It'll either give me a "Server error occured, please try again a bit later", or something similar to "Cannot find method (class)(class)setNull(number,null)" depending on what I try.

So I have just been working around it by setting things to 0 instead of null, but it would be nice to have that option!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc-prepared-statement#setNull%28Integer,Integer%29), the expected second parameter is an integer. The JDBC service should have an "ENUM" to list the options, just like other services do, like [Charts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/chart-type) or [Content](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/mime-type) Services.

I guess this is a good candidate for an issue report. If you do open one on [Apps Script issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list), please be kind to share the link here in the comments.

Now, in the lack of the proper ENUM, you should try different integers there. I guess you'll get lucky with a few attempts. e.g.

```js
preparedStatement.setNull(4, 1);
//or preparedStatement.setNull(4, 2); //and so on..
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46501699/3294762

```
preparedStatement.setNull(col_index, 0); // 0 = java.sql.Types.NULL
preparedStatement.setNull(col_index, 3); // 3 = java.sql.Types.DECIMAL
preparedStatement.setNull(col_index, 4); // 4 = java.sql.Types.INTEGER
preparedStatement.setNull(col_index, 6); // 6 = java.sql.Types.FLOAT
```