# How to use registerOutParameter in google script?

Tags: jdbc, google-apps-script

How to use registerOutParameter (int parameterIndex, int sqlType) in google script?

Problem  is using parameter: sqlType. ParameterIndex does not make problems

I understand that slqType should be represent by integer - [see in documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc-callable-statement#registeroutparameterparameterindex-sqltype)

... but what integer represents sqlType : Varchar, Integer ...?

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is a way to refer to the SQL Type by name without having to remember the list of java.sql.Types to get the int but I haven't found in Google Apps Script documentation anything yet

In the meantime in order to find the SQL Type use the following list

- ARRAY    2003
- BIGINT   -5
- BINARY   -2
- BIT  -7
- BLOB 2004
- BOOLEAN  16
- CHAR 1
- CLOB 2005
- DATALINK 70
- DATE 91
- DECIMAL  3
- DISTINCT 2001
- DOUBLE   8
- FLOAT    6
- INTEGER  4
- JAVA_OBJECT  2000
- LONGNVARCHAR -16
- LONGVARBINARY    -4
- LONGVARCHAR  -1
- NCHAR    -15
- NCLOB    2011
- NULL 0
- NUMERIC  2
- NVARCHAR -9
- OTHER    1111
- REAL 7
- REF  2006
- ROWID    -8
- SMALLINT 5
- SQLXML   2009
- STRUCT   2002
- TIME 92
- TIMESTAMP    93
- TINYINT  -6
- VARBINARY    -3
- VARCHAR  12

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.sql.Types

Answer (score 0):

You may check this [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html#registerOutParameter(int,%20int)). It stated that the parameters should be:

- `parameterIndex` - the first parameter is 1, the second is 2, and so on
- `sqlType` - the JDBC type code defined by java.sql.Types. **If the parameter is of JDBC type NUMERIC or DECIMAL, the version of registerOutParameter that accepts a scale value should be used.**

As you've seen in this sample: [google-apps-script.jdbc.d.ts](https://github.com/motemen/dts-google-apps-script/blob/master/google-apps-script/google-apps-script.jdbc.d.ts), you should use it as `Integer`.

```
registerOutParameter(parameterIndex: Integer, sqlType: Integer): void;
```

Comment: This is a theory. But how to use it in practice? Write an example of a job! ;)

Comment: ... when I want to use the first parameter as Integer what I should write: registerOutParameter (1,1), registerOutParameter (1,2), registerOutParameter (1,3) ... etc. ?