# How can I replace empty cells value with null when inserting into database from Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to insert the spreadsheet data into a mysql database. The problem is that some cells in the 'CUSTOMER' column are empty and this causes the following error when trying to run the code:

"Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'CLIENTE' at row 1"

I'm trying to replace empty cells with 'null' value when preparing the query, but I'm not getting it.

I thank the help of all.

Thanks

**Spreadsheet:**
[image: zoom 100%]

```
function writeManyRecords() {
  
    const conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('FREEZERS');
    const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    const start = new Date();
    var stmt = conn.prepareStatement('INSERT INTO FREEZERS ' +  '(PATRIMONIO,DESCRICAO,CLIENTE,LOCAL_ESTOQUE,LOCAL_ANTERIOR_ESTOQUE) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
    for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        stmt.setString(1,data[i][0]);
        stmt.setString(2,data[i][1]);
        if(!data[i][2] === '') {
            stmt.setString(3,data[i][2]);
        }
        stmt.setNull(3,4);
        stmt.setString(4,data[i][3]);
        stmt.setString(5,data[i][4]);
        stmt.addBatch();
        Logger.log('patrimonio: '+data[i][0]+'descricao: ' + data[i][1] +' cliente: '+ data[i][2])
    }

    const batch = stmt.executeBatch();
    conn.commit();
    conn.close();

    const end = new Date();
    Logger.log('Time elapsed: %sms for %s rows.', end - start, batch.length);
  }
```

Comment: It worked, 'null' values were successfully inserted into the database. But all values of column 'CLIENTES' were entered as null.
[Image](https://pasteboard.co/vSYsDEBUrOHI.png)

Comment: I think it because there is no `else` statement. See my answer.

Comment: Have you tried to add `else` statement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a guess:

```
if (!data[i][2] === '') { stmt.setString(3,data[i][2]) }
else { stmt.setNull(3,0) } // second number: 0 - null, 4 - integer, etc
```

[How to use registerOutParameter in google script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45116646/how-to-use-registeroutparameter-in-google-script/46501699#46501699)

Comment: It was still sending only null values. I changed the code a little and it worked in this version:
`if (data[i][2]==='') { stmt.setNull(3,0) }
else { stmt.setString(3,data[i][2]) }`

Thanks for the guidance.